# Compare two folder content

Tags: ubuntu, diff

How can I compare two folder content under linux.
I'm using `diff` but I want to display only the files with the same names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least you can use

`diff -s dir otherdir | grep -v "Only in"`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

ls $1 >/tmp/$$1
ls $2 >/tmp/$$2

join /tmp/$$1 /tmp/$$2

rm /tmp/$$1
rm /tmp/$$2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

D1=/tmp/1
D2=/tmp/2
f1=$(find "$D1" -type f)
f2=$(find "$D2" -type f)

for i in $f1; do 
    echo $f2 | grep $(basename $i) >/dev/null && echo $i
done
```